# IDEA - Need to list a number of labels/linklabels in a container, with scrollbars

Tags: c#, label

So, in a new form I create programmatically some labels and linklabels.
The number is NOT known by the start of the program. And I need to display them in a container or something, and when they are too many, the container should display a vertical scrollbar..

My Form is must have a fixed size

I tried Panel, LinkLabel but no success, meaning it doesn't show a scrollbar and some of the controls don't show up

Do you have any ideas?

(I want to make something like a table of contents, but which doesn't have a fixed number of items)

Thank you...

Some code:

```
for(int i=0; i<number ;i++)
{
   Label l=new Label();
   l.Name = i + ".label";
   this.Controls.Add(l); // need to replace "this" with name of a control
   l.Location(50, i * 20 + 50);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What container should I use?

Comment: Is this winforms or webforms?

Comment: winform. I've tried even with richtextbox but ..nothing

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a Panel, and setting its AutoScroll property to TRUE. Now it works.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @tiago This is not "thank you", it's the asker reporting how the problem was solved. Since there is no other answer, it's the best answer this question got.